# SED and whole line

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to create spec files for my packages.
To list files I am using `find` command and redirecting it to a file:

```
readonly TOPDIR=`pwd` 
cd package_folder
find . -iname >>$TOPDIR/list_files
```

Now my problem is I need to add prefix `%dir` for every directory otherwise I get file listed twice error.
Suppose content of my file is:

```
$ cat list_files
/bin
/bin/file_a
/bin/my_folder
/bin/my_folder/file_b
```

What I did was looked for dir's

```
for file_name in `cat $TOPDIR/list_files`
do
  chk_1=`ls -l $file_name |grep "^d"`
  if [ "chk_1" ] ;then
   sed -i "s@^$file_name@%dir $file_name@" $TOPDIR/list_files
  fi
done
```

Now my output file(list_files) looks like this:

```
%dir /bin
%dir /bin/file_a
%dir /bin/my_folder
%dir /bin/my_folder/file_b
```

Reason being `/bin` is a directory so it replaces `/bin` with `%dir`.
Well, it's kinda strange as I haven't given `@g` option but still it's replacing all `/bin`.
Is there any way to include `"\n"` in `sed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current technique, make sure that the pattern matches the whole line with `$` to mark the end of the line:

```
sed -i "s@^$file_name\$@%dir $file_name@" $TOPDIR/list_files
```

The backslash is needed to prevent the shell from expanding `$@`; `sed` does not see the backslash.

Comment: Thanks that works..and now i know my logic to look for dir was wrong :D

Comment: right logic is :chk_1=\`ls -l \\`dirname $file_name\\` |grep -w \\`basename $file_name\\` |grep "^d"\`

Answer (score 1):

You're script is very error prone. Use this instead:

```
while IFS= read -r file_name
do
   [ -d "$file_name" ] && pfx="%dir " || pfx=""
   printf "%s%s\n" "$pfx" "$file_name"
done < "$TOPDIR/list_files" > tmp &&
mv tmp "$TOPDIR/list_files"
```

It will protect you from file names containing spaces, tabs, @ signs, backslashes, etc., etc. and will stop you from corrupting your original file if you run out of space for a tmp file (which sed creates on the fly).

Comment: Thanks :) ,luckily none of my files had @ ,space,etc but i will add this

Comment: done < "$TOPDIR/list_files" > tmp &&
what is use of these line ?

Comment: `cmd < file > tmp && mv tmp file` is how to modify the contents of your original file with the result of running a command on that file. `> tmp` tells the shell to redirect stdout to a tmp file and the `&& mv tmp file` tells the shell to execute the `mv` command if the original command (`cmd`) succeeded.